# Monitor changes to an array object

Tags: swift, swift-array

I have no idea if this is possible at all, but it would save me from a lot of stress and bad code. Is it possible to monitor whenever an array gets updated? For example, method A changes the array `a=[1,2,3]` to `a=[1,2,3,4`], is it possible to have a sort of delegate that gets triggered when `a` is updated?

Comment: Why not implement your own protocol observable and make the arrays in question conform to that?

Comment: Alternatively make a wrapper object that, when updating the Array, calls a didChangeArray() or flips a public bool that you can check.

Comment: It's time for bed here. I'll provide it tomorrow (unless someone else comes up wit a smart idea)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If your array is a property in your class, you can use property observers.  willSet is called before the change, didSet is called after.  It is really easy.

```
var myArray:[Int] = [1, 3, 4] {
    didSet {
        println("arrayChanged")
    }
}
```

This will print array changed if I add an Int, remove and Int, etc.  I generally put it on one line though:

```
var myArray:[Int] = [1, 3, 4] { didSet { println("arrayChanged") } }
```

Comment: Thank you, it was very helpful

Comment: Is there any way to monitor internal array changes? Like myArray.append(x)?

Comment: @PavelAlexeev If you define the `set` for your array it will call for all `removeAll`, `append` etc changes.